# How to unstage changes but keep tracking a file in Mercurial?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial

For example, I have 2 files: `A` and `B`

Both of them are tracked and modified then. What I want to do is to commit one file at one time.

In git, I can do it like this:

```
git add A
git commit -m "add A"
git add B
git commit -m "add B"
```

But in Mercurial, I don't know how to do the same thing. Because in the first commit, the changes of B will also be commit automatically. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to read `hg help commit` *carefully*:

```
hg commit [OPTION]... [FILE]...

aliases: ci

commit the specified files or all outstanding changes
```

i.e if you add filename(s), Mercurial commit **only specified** changed files, without filenamemes - all

`hg ci -m "Add a" A & hg ci -m "Add B" B` will produce two changesets (for the cost of 2 commands instead of 4, BTW)